# How to access IAM resources using temporary credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to access IAM resources of a AWS account A from a different AWS account B using assume role thing. I've assume role permission policy setup in both the AWS accounts (trustee account and trusted account). Let's say the role name is dummyRole exists in AWS A and it has create user permission and create access keys permissions and I'm permitted to assume dummyRole from AWS B.

I'm trying to create an IAM user in AWS account A by assuming dummyRole from AWS account A. I'm stuck at a place where once we get into the AWS A using temporary credentials what needs to be done to have visibility of the IAM functions.
Here is the code snippet I tried but observing `AttributeError: 'IAM' object has no attribute 'User'`

```
import boto3
import os, sys

role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::A:role/dummyRole'

client = boto3.client('sts')

response = client.assume_role(RoleArn=role_arn, RoleSessionName='createCrossAccountUser')
local_creds = response.get('Credentials')
print (local_creds)

access_key = local_creds.get('AccessKeyId', '')
secret_key = local_creds.get('SecretAccessKey', '')
session_token = local_creds.get('SessionToken', '')

iam_resource = boto3.client('iam', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
                                    aws_session_token=session_token)
print (iam_resource)

iam_resource.User('dummyUserForSubaccount')
```

Comment: You want `boto3.resource('iam')` instead of `boto3.client('iam')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update below line with **boto3.resource**

```
iam_resource = boto3.resource('iam', aws_access_key_id=access_key, aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
                                aws_session_token=session_token)
```

Whenever you got the error like

> AttributeError: '<**AWS-Service**>' object has no attribute '<**attribute-name**>'

Always check boto3 document for that service. As per your case

[For Client object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#client)

[For resource objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#service-resource)

As per document, User() method is available for Resource not for Client. Same logic you have to follow for all AWS services.

You can also create user like this. just replace last line of your code with this.

```
iam_resource.create_user(UserName='dummyUserForSubaccount')
```

Comment: Thanks. While I'm running into access denied issue for the create_user with the assume role (I've root access and root is allowed to assume dummyRole) it seems with the above solution at least I'm able to get into the other AWS account.

Comment: Due to SCP issue I was running to access denied error. SCP issue resolved. Now, able to assume the role and create the user successfully.